# How can I find element in list that only half-matches DateTime object in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

I have a list that contains DateTime like so:

```
[2021-03-05 00:00:00.000, 2021-03-12 08:00:00.000Z, 2021-03-19 08:00:00.000Z, 2021-03-26 08:00:00.000Z, 2021-04-02 08:00:00.000Z, 2021-04-09 08:00:00.000Z, 2021-04-16 08:00:00.000Z, 2021-04-23 08:00:00.000Z, 2021-04-30 08:00:00.000Z, 2021-05-07 08:00:00.000Z, 2021-05-14 08:00:00.000Z, 2021-05-21 08:00:00.000Z, 2021-05-28 08:00:00.000Z, 2021-06-04 08:00:00.000Z, 2021-06-11 08:00:00.000Z]
```

I need the full DateTime list items, however I want to be able to query for "half-matches" like so:

```
if (dates.contains(DateTime(2021, 3, 12))) {
    print('Afermative');
  } else {
    print('Nope');
  }
```

Currently prints nope, obviously.

Is there a simple way of querying for such "half-matches" like above?

Comment: No such methods in DateTime. It means you should write your own to compare `.year`, `.month` and `.day`, then pass it to `firstWhere()` or alike.

Comment: Sorry, please explain. I do not understand what you're saying.

Comment: I explained in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such built-in method. You should create your own.

1. Define a method that returns if two `DateTime` objects have the same date:

```dart
bool areSameDay(DateTime one, DateTime two) {
  return one.day == two.day && one.month == two.month && one.year == two.year;
}
```

2. Call `firstWhere` on the list:

```dart
final targetDate = DateTime(2021, 3, 12);

try {
  final dateTime = dates.firstWhere((date) => areSameDay(date, targetDate));
  // Found
} catch (_) {
  // Not found
}
```

Also note that `contains()` would not do even for complete matches. This is because it compares references to `DateTime` objects and not their contents. To compare `DateTime` object contents, use `dateTime.compareTo(DateTime other)`

Comment: Ahhh, i get it. This works, thanks for the input! I want to try one more method tomorrow with https://pub.dev/packages/dart_date

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to format your date.
You can look up the options of the format of the dates here - [Link](https://medium.com/flutter-community/working-with-dates-in-dart-e81c70911811)

```
var newFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

if (dates.singleWhere(
        (element) =>
            element.contains(newFormat.format(DateTime(2021, 3, 12))),
        orElse: () => null) !=
    null) {
  print('Afermative');
} else {
  print('Nope');
}
```

Comment: Looks nice and simple, will try it out tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize your `dates` variable was a list of `DateTime`, I have now updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Jiffy](https://github.com/jama5262/jiffy) package, it supports date querying. See below

```
var jiffy = Jiffy(DateTime(2021, 3, 12));
// or
var jiffy = Jiffy.parse("2021/3/12");
// or
var jiffy = Jiffy.parseFromList([2021, 3, 12]);


dates.forEach((date) {
    var isSame = jiffy.isSame(Jiffy.parse(date));
    if (isSame) {
      print('Afermative');
    } else {
      print('Nope');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Hey Jama I could not get this to work, throws error DateTime is not a subtype of int (something like that, lost the error and went on, sorry).

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that your `dates` variable was a list of `DateTime`, I have now updated my answer, to check if each `DateTime` in the list matches the target